# Is there a way I can get an Enum value by its number in the sequence?

Tags: c#, xamarin, enums, xamarin.forms

I have this enum:

```
public enum PTI
{
    UserInput = 0,
    Five = 5,
    Ten = 10,
    Fifteen = 15
}

public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static string Text(this PTI time)
    {
        switch (time)
        {
            case PTI.UserInput: return "User Input";
            case PTI.Ten: return "10 seconds";
            case PTI.Five: return "5 seconds";
            case PTI.Fifteen: return "15 seconds";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

It's a simple case but I am using it as an example. In my code I need to pass the value of the enum to a function so I came up with this:

```
if (selectedIndex == 1) App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, PTI.UserInput);
if (selectedIndex == 2) App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, PTI.Five);
if (selectedIndex == 3) App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, PTI.Ten);
if (selectedIndex == 4) App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, PTI.Fifteen);
```

It's not ideal.  Maybe a Case would help here but my point is that all I get is a number from 1 to 4 and from this I need to get the ENUM value.

Is there some way that I could get the ENUM value from the value of selectedIndex without an if or case construct?

Background - Here's where the value of selectedIndex comes from. It's from a picker in a Xamarin Form XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="ptiPicker" IsVisible="false" SelectedIndexChanged="ptiOnPickerSelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <Picker.Items>
                                                <x:String>User input</x:String>
                                                <x:String>5 seconds</x:String>
                                                <x:String>10 seconds</x:String>
                                                <x:String>15 seconds</x:String>
                                            </Picker.Items>
                                        </Picker>
```

Note:

If it was possible I would be happy to add some extension method to the enum if that would help get what I needed. Just not sure how to do that.

Comment: From where do you get `selectedIndex` ? how are you displaying enum values in the control?

Comment: You can find my answer below to get the index of the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the index of the Enum value.

```
// Below code sample how to find the index of Enum.
// Sample to show how to find the index of item
PTI p = PTI.Ten; 
int index = Array.IndexOf(Enum.GetValues(p.GetType()), p);
Console.WriteLine(index); // Output: 2 because of value PTI.Ten
```

So, finally solution for you to replace all if statements with just one statement.

```
PTI pti = (PTI)(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PTI))).GetValue(selectedIndex-1); // selectedIndex-1 because the index is 0 based.
App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, pti);
```

Comment: that must be the answer

Comment: This uses reflection, right? If you don't mind the overhead, this works. If you want less overhead, some sort of static lookup via a function or an array would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your int with PTI like in this program

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(""+(PTI)2);
        Console.WriteLine(""+(PTI)5);
    }
}

public enum PTI
{
    UserInput = 0,
    Five = 5,
    Ten = 10,
    Fifteen = 15
}
```

If the integer has a valid value existing in the enum you get the enum, if not you will get the integer unchanged as the result of the program above shows below:

```
2
Five
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but may be you should try to fill items with elements of your enum directly?
In WPF It goes simply like this. And if you want to convert enum elements to string and back, you can use ValueConverter
The example below is **from** **WPF**!

```
        <ComboBox
        // properties here
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.EngineType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Model:EEngineType>Diesel</Model:EEngineType>
        <Model:EEngineType>Gas</Model:EEngineType>
        <Model:EEngineType>Biofuel</Model:EEngineType>
        <Model:EEngineType>Electrical</Model:EEngineType>
    </ComboBox>
```

and EEngineType

```
public enum EEngineType
{
    Diesel,
    Gas,
    Biofuel,
    Electrical
}
```

May be you should look around something like this, so you won't need to convert anything and just pass selectedItem to your method.

**OR** 
in another way you can try to use something like this

```
readonly TCollection _PITCollection;
// ctor here
 _PITCollection = new TCollection<PIT> { PIT.UserInput, PIT.Five, PIT... };
```

Where instead of `TCollection` you write any collection type you want.
And than you can use binding and call

```
App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, myPicker.SelectedItem);
```

or you can use you previous style and call

```
App.DB.UpdateSetting(Settings.Pti, _PITCollection[selectedIndex]);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert it as an integer to get the value.

`Convert.ToInt32(PTI.Fifteen)`

[image]

[Picker items](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/) are in a form of `string` so what you can do is to get the text of the [selected index](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20877/geting-the-value-of-a-picker-in-xamarin-forms) of your picker and parse it to only get the number from item.

```
picker.Items [picker.SelectedIndex];
```

e.g.

```
var selectedValue = "15 seconds"; //this will be your selected value in picker
var splitx = selectedValue.Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(PTI.Fifteen));

if (Convert.ToInt32(splitx[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(PTI.Fifteen))
{
    Console.WriteLine("selected value is - 15 seconds");
}
```

[image]

You can also try to do a `Dictionary` like in the [Xamarin example here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/)

Hope this helps you...

Comment: I want to go the other way.  I want to get PTI.Fifteen from the number 15

Comment: what you can do is to get the text of the selected item and `substring` it to only get the number, e.g. ("15 seconds" get only "15" and convert it to Int32 and compare it to the values of your Enum)

Comment: or you  can put a delimiter on your text for items in your picker. e.g. "15-seconds" for splitting up the text easily using `split`

Comment: Alan is trying to get the index of the the items in the Enum not the values. Please find below the solution to get the index and based on that get the enum value dynamically.

Comment: @Habeeb Alan is getting the value from the selected item in a `Picker`. he wants to get the equivalent value of the item from his picker item using his `Enum` but it is not possible since he only got an index selected. to do that he can either get the text selected item and parse it to get the number of seconds the user selected in the picker

Comment: @JericCruz. Actually there is a way to get the index of the Enum based on the SelectedIndex of his Picker. This is the solution I have given in my Answer.